# qt error: undefined reference to `str2ba'

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I am new to qt. I am using qt creator successfully to create ui. I need bluetooth functionality from qt. I had earlier version of code running through terminal. I copy pasted the running code. I get a lot of undefined references.

error: undefined reference to `str2ba'
error: undefined reference to`sqlite3_open'
error: undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
 error: undefined reference to`sqlite3_errmsg'
error: undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
 error: undefined reference to`sqlite3_close'
 error: undefined reference to `hci_get_route'
 error: undefined reference to`hci_open_dev'
 error: undefined reference to `hci_inquiry'
 error: undefined reference to`ba2str'
error: undefined reference to `hci_read_remote_name'
 error: undefined reference to`ba2str'

Is there anything like linux apis can not be used in qt? how to integrate the app then? Or do I have to link libraries like -lpthread -lbluetooth etc.

Comment: Why do you think it has something to do with Qt? Seems like you just didn't include some headers in your project.

Answer (score 2):

"Undefined reference..." seems to be a linker error. 
Do you link against libsqlite3 and libbluetooth? 
Adding

```
-lsqplite3 -lbluetooth
```

to your ld/g++ command line helps in that case

Comment: how/where to add those link options, today is the 1st day I started with Qt. So, I do not know. Can u be more specific

Comment: I made ome change now I get error <command-line>:-1: error: macro names must be identifiers

Comment: How do you compile your code? Do you have a Makefile or do you use some IDE like Eclipse or QtCreator?

Comment: I use qt creator

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html add libsqlite3 and libbluetooth as 'System Libraries'. Maybe without the "lib" prefix, so just 'sqlite' and 'bluetooth'. I do not use QtCreator so I cannot tell you exactly, unfortunately...